# WCF Timeout exception on service call

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF service that is giving the following error on live

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 19/06/2012 10:39:09 
Event time (UTC): 19/06/2012 09:39:09 
Event ID: 501c1b630958413db7c7f746b0a467f7 
Event sequence: 74336 
Event occurrence: 742 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT-1-129844753959691296 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: <private> 
    Machine name: <private> 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6112 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\<private> 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TimeoutException 
    Exception message: The HTTP request to '<private>/EndPoint.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://<private>/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: <private> 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\<private>  

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 110 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\<private>  
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)


Custom event details:
```

Our site is down and I don't know what to do here.  Any ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Can you post the client/service configurations and the way you are calling the service from client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the [SendTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout.aspx) and [ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx) properties in service/client configurations.

[WCF Service , how to increase the timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520283/wcf-service-how-to-increase-the-timeout)