# Thread Abort Exception in WCF Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, threadabortexception

I am getting a weird error while running my WCF service. Thread abort receiving while running i searched for many solution nothing helped am posting my error below.

I am calling a WCF service from the webpage. The WCF service executes a stored procedure in a for loop, whether this causes thread abort? I even tried increasing the httpruntime execution timeout in `web.config` but without success.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SNI_ConnWrapper* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
   at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Your call to DB is being time out. Check that your SP takes how much time in Managment console ?

Comment: Seems to be a timeout issue. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520283/wcf-service-how-to-increase-the-timeout) to see if changing the WCF service timeouts can help.

Comment: When i run the same code with the same db from server am not facing any issues, but when i running the same in server am getting the issues @MairajAhmad..

Comment: closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"  my binding config... @ChrisC73

Comment: I think we need some more information here: 1) How long does the service take before throwing the exception? 2) what does the WCF client and service config look like?

Comment: Another possibility is something [writing to your website's bin directory](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2007/10/solution-to-thread-was-being-aborted.html), causing it to restart the app pool.

Comment: 1.the service takes 1 min before throwing error. 2.Both bindings and configuration are same for both client and service.

Comment: You need to share the code that causes this exception and it would also be helpful if you could indicate what the connection timeout settings are on your Sql Connection.

Comment: You made my day @ChrisC73, in my case I was writing a config file in the bin directly of an ASP.NET app, and it was systematically causing ThreadAbortException!